# Probability Integral Transform of an Exponential Random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I came across Probability Integral transform which states that if random variable $X$ has distribution function $F(x)$ then $F(X)$ has Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

I was applying this concept to the case of Exponential random variable.
whose PDF is $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Whose CDF is $F(x) = 1 -e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x > 0$ and $0$ if $x \leq 0$.

Now $F(X) = 1 -e^{-\lambda X}$ for $X > 0$ and  $0$ if $X \leq 0$.

Now what is the distribution of $F(X)$ , observing it as the function of the random variable $X$.

Applying the formula for $X   $ has density function $f(x)$ then for $Y =g(X)$ the density function of $Y$ is $f(g^{-1}(y) |\frac{d(g^{-1}(y))}{dy}|) ; 0<y<1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Applying the above to our function of rv $X$ which is $F(X)$ we get - 
the density function of $F(X)$ as $\frac{y}{\lambda (1-y)} ; o<y<1$ and $0$ otherwise.is this correct?

$\textbf{EDIT :}$

I got $g^{-1}(y) = \frac{-1}{\lambda}\ln(1-y)$ , $f(g^{-1}(y)) = y$ and $\frac{d(g^{-1}(y))}{dy} = \frac{1}{\lambda(1-y)}$.
So combining we get the density function of $F(X) $ say $h(y) = \frac{y}{\lambda(1-y)}$.

Now I am in doubt that I should have been getting Uniform density function but the above doesnot seem to follow Uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the fact for continuous distributions that therefore have invertible CDFs is: $$ P(F(X)\le z) = P(X \le F^{-1}(z)) = F((F^{-1}(z)) = z.$$ (The generalization to arbitrary distributions is just a matter of properly defining a generalized $F^{-1},$ but that's not important here.)

So you are making a calculation error.

Doing it the other way with the PDF, you have $Y = 1-\exp(-\lambda X)$ so that $X  =-\frac{\ln(1-Y)}{\lambda}.$ So by the standard formula, $$f_Y(y) = \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|f_X\left(\frac{-\ln(1-y)}{\lambda}\right) = \frac{1}{\lambda(1-y)}\lambda e^{-\lambda \left(-\frac{\ln(1-y)}{\lambda}\right)}=1.$$

So either way, you get a uniform distribution, as promised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am unable to identify the error in my steps, any help on that, I just did an edit.

Comment: @BAYMAX  $f(g^{-1}(y))=y$ is wrong. $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and $g^{-1}(y) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln(1-y)$. Plugging in gives $$f(g^{-1}(y))=\lambda e^{\ln(1-y)} =\lambda(1-y).$$

Comment: Nice, I found it, I was applying by mistake to $F(x)$. Thanks!